# add the event dynamically to body> with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need the event to result in:

```
<body onload="window.scrollTo(0, 1);">
```

How do i do this dynamically?

I've tried

```
function loadPage() {
    $('body').append('scrollTo(0, 0);');
}
```

and

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].append('scrollTo(0, 0);');
```

but no luck.

Comment: Ok, so...what are you trying to do? Scroll to position 0, 0?

Comment: That's what I thought but pages default to position 0,0 when loaded?

Comment: Probably this is a mobile app and s/he's trying to get rid of the nav bar in iOS.  Questions are so much more fun when we have to deduce what the question actually is ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

did you try this:

```
$('body').attr('onload', 'window.scrollTo(0, 1);');
```

Or the faster (slightly):

```
$(document.body).attr('onload', 'window.scrollTo(0, 1);');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document.body).on("load", function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery Mobile, you should bind `$.mobile.silentScroll(y)` to pagecreate. Like this.

```
$( '#pageId' ).live( 'pagecreate',function(event){ $.mobile.silentScroll(1) } );
```